# MySQL Multiple Subqueries vs. whole queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering which way to get data from a MySQL database has better performance characteristics.

Using subqueries within one main query:

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(`number`) FROM `table`) as `number_sum`,
(SELECT MAX(`number`) FROM `table`) as `number_max`,
(SELECT MIN(`number`) FROM `table`) as `number_min`
```

Or, 3 distinct `SELECT` statements retrieving the same data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since these three aggregates come from the same table with the same `WHERE` conditions, you have no need for subselects.  All three of the aggregates are operating on the same row grouping (no `GROUP BY` specified, so one row for the whole table), so they can all exist in the `SELECT` list directly.

```
SELECT
  SUM(number) AS number_sum,
  MAX(number) AS number_max,
  MIN(number) AS number_min
FROM `table`
```

If any of the aggregates needs to be based on different conditions you would filter in a `WHERE` clause, then you will need to either use a subselect for the differing condition, or do a cartesian join. This subselect and the following `LEFT JOIN` method should be equivalent, performance-wise for aggregates returning only one row:

```
SELECT
  /* Unique filtering condition - must be done in a subselect */
  (SELECT SUM(number) FROM `table` WHERE `somecolumn` = `somevalue`) AS number_sum,
  MAX(number) AS number_max,
  MIN(number) AS number_min
FROM `table`
```

Or equivalent to the query above, you can `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery *with no `ON` clause*. This should only be done in situations when you know the subquery will return only one row.  Otherwise, you will end up with a cartesian product -- as many rows as returned by one side of the join *multiplied by* the number of rows returned by the other side.

This is handy if you need to return a few columns with one set of `WHERE` clause conditions and a few columns with a different set of `WHERE` conditions, but only *one* row from each side of the `JOIN`. In this case, it should be faster to `JOIN` than to do *two* subselects with the same `WHERE` clause.

**This should be faster....**

```
SELECT
  /* this one has two aggregates sharing a WHERE condition */
  subq.number_sum_filtered,
  subq.number_max_filtered,
  /* ...and two aggregates on the main table with no WHERE clause filtering */
  MAX(`table`.number) AS number_max,
  MIN(`table`.number) AS number_min
FROM
  `table`
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       SUM(number) AS number_sum_filtered,
       MAX(number) AS number_max_filtered
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `somecolumn = `somevalue`
  ) subq /* No ON clause here since there's no common column to join on... */
```

**Than this...**

```
SELECT
  /* Two different subselects each over the same filtered set */
  (SELECT SUM(number) FROM `table` WHERE `somecolumn` = `somevalue`) AS number_sum_filtered,
  (SELECT MAX(number) FROM `table` WHERE `somecolumn` = `somevalue`) AS number_max_filtered,
  MAX(`table`.number) AS number_max,
  MIN(`table`.number) AS number_min
FROM
  `table`
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it, but remember to put backticks around field and table names - especially here because "table" is a keyword.

Comment: @Kolink added, but `table` is almost never _really_ the table name :)

Comment: True, but I've used keywords as table/field names in the past (such as a timestamp literally named "timestamp" - good for current_timestamp defaults)