# Performance-wise comparison for sub-query/multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Which is performance-wise best way to use query in PHP/MySQL?

1.Sub-query:

```
SELECT column1, (sub-query) as column2 FROM join_multiple_tables WHERE some condition GROUP BY columns
```

2.multiple queries:

```
SELECT column1 FROM join_multiple_tables WHERE some condition GROUP BY columns
```

Then execute multiple query based on column 1 value using PHP. So which is the best and efficient way for less execution cost?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241060/mysql-multiple-subqueries-vs-whole-queries

Comment: You forget about Php, this queries performance will be evaluated at sql level only, using sub query is not a good idea, do you have any column common in the tow tables ?

Comment: @AshutoshArya Yes, I have common column, but I have to use subquery as `JOIN` will not fulfil my need. And performance combining PHP/MySQL

Comment: @Parixit: What exactly are you trying to achieve? just at high level.

Comment: @AshutoshArya I have 2 option as I can use sub-query or execute multiple query through loop in PHP. SO which will be cost efficient way?

Comment: Going Ideally Please go for multiple query. Sub query won't be cost effective.